# Combine data from Firebase and Google analytics into 1 view

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have a website, iOS and Android apps. For the website I use Google Analytics and for the apps I use Firebase. Currently I have to switch between Analytics and Firebase but I was wondering if there was a way to create a combined view.

To start with, I would like something simple like the total number of active users at the moment across all 3 platforms. Is this possible at all?

Longer term it would be great if sales data between the 3 could also be combined.

Is there a way to create something like a Google sheet that pulls this data in real time?

Answer (score 0):

I too wish for a combined view. My research suggests we cobble together our own by exporting event data from GA and Firebase Analytics into Google BigQuery and construct our own views in there. But then you don’t get the nice dashboards and other data that they infer, just table data on the events tracked.